# How does rails detect which environment it is in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, frameworks, development-environment, production-environment

Out of curiosity, how does Rails detect which environment it is in when running on a server, ie either Production or Development?

When I run a rails app locally on my mac/linux machine, it know's it's in a development environment, but when it's deployed to a remote linux machine, it knows it's in production.

How is this so? What are the major implicit differences as far how the app runs, which resources it uses, etc?

Also is the Production/Development dichotomy fixed and part of the framework, or is it possible to establish something like a "staging" environment, that's for all intents and purposes the same as production but meant for testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let me quote from the 'rails 4 way' book

> The current environment can be specified via the environment variable
>   `RAILS_ENV`, which names the desired mode of operation and corresponds
>   to an environment definition file in the `config/environments` folder.
>   you can also set the environment variable `RACK_ENV` or as a last
>   resort you may rely on the default being development.

I believe you could add your environments by easily creating a new file inside the `config/environments` folder, and start it easily by adding the `RAILS_ENV` while running the server

`rails s RAILS_ENV=staging` or any other environment you want